# giving addClass to few class (not all of them)

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example, i have four classes with id of "1" to "4".
Then i want to add "hidden" to id of "2" and "3".

with this code:

```
this.block.addClass("hidden");
```

The "hidden" added to all four classes with id of "1" to "4".
How can i use this code to add "hidden" only to id of "2" and "3"?

I should say sorry if my question is so simple, it is the first day that i am coding with javascript language. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Thanks for your response, here is one part of html:   

    <a class="button wide" id="number-creator"> Add new number </a>
                  <div class="sidebar-divider hidden"></div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter elements in a jQuery object with the [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. Use commas to indicate "or" between selector strings:

```
this.block.filter('#2, #3').addClass("hidden");
```

But assuming your HTML is valid and doesn't contain duplicate `id`s, you shouldn't need `this.block` at all, just select `#2` and `#3` immediately:

```
$('#2, #3').addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can filter elements like @CertainPerformance said with the following code:

```
this.block.filter('#2, #3').addClass("hidden");
```

However, since it's your first day using JS and jQuery you may not know that you can also refer to elements by their IDs:

```
$('#2').addClass("hidden");
```

You can also select by attributes. For example, if you're using data-id it would be:

```
$('[data-id="2"]').addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i really appreciate it